# How to show $x \in R(P)$ when if $P$ is orthogonal projector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection, projection-matrices

For an orthogonal projector $P$, if $\|Px\|_2=\|x\|_2$, show that $x \in R(P)$, where $R(P)$ is the range of $P$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $P$ is an $n \times n$ matrix.

We need to show there exist $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x=Py$.

My try:

Since $\|Px\|_2=\|x\|_2$, we get $\|Px\|_2^2=\|x\|_2^2$, i.e.,

$$
x^TP^TPx=x^Tx
$$

How would you come up with $x=Py$?

Comment: Hint: every point in the range of a projection projects to itself.

Comment: @Theo Bendit : Did you have another way to proof rather than the one that is posted? Could you post your proof?

Comment: Nothing different enough, no. My point is that figuring out which $y$ satisfies $x = Py$ (if there is a $y$ that works) is easy: choose $y = x$. That is, you can prove $x = Px$, or $x$ is not in the range of $P$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\|x\|^{2}=\|Px+(x-Px)\|^{2}=\|Px\|^{2}+\|x-Px\|^{2}$ because $Px$ is orthogonal to $(I-P)(x)$. So $x-Px=0$.